# Tenant 'xxx' not found while calling MS Graph API on behalf of a user

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to implement the on behalf flow with Azure AD following [this Microsoft sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-nodejs-webapi-onbehalfof-azurefunctions) documentation, all is good on the client-side but in the
the service app side (the azure function that obtains another Access Token using the on user's behalf and calls the MS Graph API on user's behalf again), it fails to obtain the access a new access token (getNewAccessToken) and shows:

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "AADSTS90002: Tenant 'xyz' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.\r\nTrace ID: xxx \r\nCorrelation ID: yyy \r\nTimestamp: 2021-01-04 07:17:15Z",
"error_codes": [
    90002
],
"timestamp": "2021-01-04 07:17:15Z",
"trace_id": "xxx",
"correlation_id": "yyy",
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=90002"
}
```

any clue how to solve this issue?

Comment: As the error says, make sure you're using the correct tenantId or name like xyz.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Check with your tenant Id/name if you navigate to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<TenantId>>/.well-known/openid-configuration` then it gives result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your error message, you can navigate to your Azure Active Directory and make sure your TenantID matches what's in your application.

Error Message:
AADSTS90002: Tenant 'xyz' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID.

[TenantID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAlgB.png)

Comment: tenant didn't have any active subscription